# Why %rax value is 0xfffffffffffffffd?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb, x86-64, coredump

I've got several core dumps in C++ code inside [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) of `std::unordered_map`. The code that causes core dump roughly looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> > fields;
fields[key].push_back(value);
```

I can't reproduce it on my local box, I only have several core dumps. They all were caused by segmentation fault inside `operator[]`. Here is apart of disassemble of the offending code:

```
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function std::__detail::_Map_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>, true>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&):
   0x000000000043fc70 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000043fc71 <+1>: mov    $0xc70f6907,%edx
   0x000000000043fc76 <+6>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000043fc79 <+9>: push   %r15
   0x000000000043fc7b <+11>:    push   %r14
   0x000000000043fc7d <+13>:    mov    %rdi,%r14
   0x000000000043fc80 <+16>:    push   %r13
   0x000000000043fc82 <+18>:    push   %r12
   0x000000000043fc84 <+20>:    mov    %rsi,%r12
   0x000000000043fc87 <+23>:    push   %rbx
   0x000000000043fc88 <+24>:    sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000043fc8c <+28>:    mov    0x8(%rsi),%rsi
   0x000000000043fc90 <+32>:    mov    (%r12),%rdi
   0x000000000043fc94 <+36>:    callq  0x408cd0 <_ZSt11_Hash_bytesPKvmm@plt>
   0x000000000043fc99 <+41>:    mov    0x8(%r14),%rcx
   0x000000000043fc9d <+45>:    xor    %edx,%edx
   0x000000000043fc9f <+47>:    mov    %rax,%r13
   0x000000000043fca2 <+50>:    div    %rcx
   0x000000000043fca5 <+53>:    mov    (%r14),%rax
   0x000000000043fca8 <+56>:    mov    (%rax,%rdx,8),%rax
   0x000000000043fcac <+60>:    mov    %rdx,%r15
   0x000000000043fcaf <+63>:    test   %rax,%rax
   0x000000000043fcb2 <+66>:    je     0x43fd18 <std::__detail::_Map_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>, true>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)+168>
=> 0x000000000043fcb4 <+68>:    mov    (%rax),%rbx
   0x000000000043fcb7 <+71>:    mov    0x40(%rbx),%rsi
```

Segmentation fault occurred on `mov` instruction referencing `%rax` register:

```
=> 0x000000000043fcb4 <+68>:    mov    (%rax),%rbx
```

The problem is that the value of `%rax` is `0xfffffffffffffffd` and `mov` is trying to read at that address which causes segmentation fault:

```
(gdb) p/x $rax
$1 = 0xfffffffffffffffd
```

What could be the reason that `%rax` has a value that finally causes segmentation fault?

Comment: Probably a dangling pointer? `rax` at the point of the fault comes from `rax+rdx*8` where `rdx` is `hash(input) % k` (*k* being a field of the object, at offset 0x8) and the previous `rax` value is the pointer to the table.

Comment: Obviously `8(%r14)` contains the number of elements in an array of pointers; and `0(%r14)` contains a pointer to that array. Can you check if these values (`8(%r14)` and `0(%r14)`) are plausible?

Comment: They are seem plausible to me, this is what I got: `(gdb) x/xg $r14+0
0x7f6edf7b6f48: 0x00007f6f22b9f1b0` and `(gdb) x/xg $r14+8
0x7f6edf7b6f50: 0x0000000000000007`.

Comment: Is the program multithreaded, and if so, do multiple threads have access to the `fields` map, and if so, is this access protected by a mutex?

Comment: Yes, it is multithreaded. No multiple threads do not access `fields`, it is local variable. Actually I don't believe it is multithreading issue. Something like dangling pointer or buffer overflow is more likely, but everything is possible.

Comment: I would suggest trying to relate this to the actual members of the `field` object, either by reading the standard library source code to deduce its layout, or using gdb's source-level debugging capabilities.  It looks like `this` is in `%r14`, so something like `p *(std::unordered_map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> > *)$r14` may show you the contents of that object.  You can then try to figure out which pointer or index is erroneous, and then start investigating how it got that way.